# Centering dynamic containers on page using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently working on a system that shows multiple containers (container-fluid to be precise) on a page. These containers are configured so there's no set number of them. Each of them *should* have a automatic width and a max width.
I want there to be as much containers as possible on the same height. This works fine, but there appears to be a white space on the right side. The side between the left screen border and the left container should be equal to the space between the right container and the right screen border.
These containers contain multiple rows and colums.

I tried setting the margin to auto, removing paddings etc. I also looked up some other threads about this right space. None of these were helpful.

CSS:

```
.table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 6px!important;
    max-width: none!important;
}
.container-fluid {
    max-width: 900px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}
tr {
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.table-container {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Picture:
[image: Picture]

As you can see, the right space is much bigger.

[Site](http://robindebaets.be/leaderheads/leaderboard.php)

Answer (score 0):

It is the css `display: inline-block` on your `container-fluid` class

Comment: When setting the display to inline, the max-width refuses to work and the width becomes auto.

Comment: The width of the rows remains at 900px or smaller in chrome on my computer.

Comment: http://i.robindebaets.be/00-19-46.png when setting display to inline and leaving max-width of container-fluid on 900px

Comment: Your image is not what is happening in Chrome.  Use the DevTools in your browser and uncheck your display setting for container-fluid.
http://s160.photobucket.com/user/dominofoe/media/Capture_1.jpg.html

Comment: After unchecking the display option, the containers each go on a seperate line.

Answer (score 0):

Putting all containers in a flex box fixed the problem:

```
.container-pack {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: flex-start;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```